# How to change jest test file suffix?

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to setup `jest` to test an existing project, but all the test file name is like `someFileSpec.js` instead `someFile.spec.js`.

How can I configure `jest` to look at these files, without rename all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the [`testRegex`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testregex-string) setting in your jest settings:

```
testRegex: '(<rootDir>/test/.*|)Spec\\.jsx?$',
```